# Video from array of images ffmpeg windows php

Tags: php, image, video, ffmpeg, gif

I have an array of images src. 
`$src = array("folder1/imagejsbs124.jpg","folder2/image45125hsja.jpg", ");`

I want to convert those images into a video.mp4 creating a animated slideshow.

I searched stackoverflow but it didn't work for me.  Therefore I asked this personally and hope someone will find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try out as given here [Create a video slideshow from images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images).
Simple example to generate a video from some images using `ffmpeg` can be

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg video.mpg
```

This will bascically use all images from the current directory (named image1.jpg, image2.jpg .... imagen.jpg) to generate a video named video.mpg.

Using php you can also checkout for [FFmpeg-php](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/) which i basically a php extension for ffmpeg.

if files are in different directory then use [Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate):

Create a file concat.txt and then use it as input

```
file '/path/to/file1'
file '/path/to/file2'
file '/path/to/file3'

ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt video.mpg
```

Comment: My images aren't in same folder neither their names are in pattern

Comment: Then use Concatenate. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate. I have updated the  answer please check if it suits your requirment.

Comment: Can't I do without creating a .Text file and instead using a string?

Comment: The concat protocol is equivalent to Unix `cat` Don't think JPGs can be 'catted'.